# Webcam.js rear camera not rotating properly

Tags: webcam, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I'm using Webcam.min.js library to capture image. When i'm using **Tablet** horizontally then it's working properly. But when i'm doing **Tablet** vertically then camera not rotating.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/webcam.min.js"></script>

<h4>Take picture</h4>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="my_camera"></div>
    <input type="button" id="snap" value="Take Snapshot" ng-click="ctrl.take_snapshot()">
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-top: -35px;;margin-left: 30%;;" id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
```

Script code:

```
Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90,
        flip_horiz: true,
        constraints: {
            video: true,
            facingMode: "environment"
        }
});
Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

this.take_snapshot= function take_snapshot() {
        // take snapshot and get image data
        Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
            // display results in page
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
                '<h5>Captured on : '+new Date()+'</h5>' + 
                '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
                alert(data_uri);
        } );
}
```

I struggle a lot to fix it. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to the camera preference when using mobile.

The `navigator.getUserMedia` function is deprecated and you should instead use the newer `MediaDevices.getUserMedia` function. The link for the docs.

in your `Threex.ArToolkitSource.js` file at line `143` should then be changed to

```
var constraints = { video: { 
                   facingMode: "environment"  
                   mandatory: {
                                        maxWidth: _this.parameters.sourceWidth,
                               maxHeight: _this.parameters.sourceHeight
                    }
};
```

And if someone wants to instead use the 'selfie' camera they change "environment" to "user". You can even make a button to choose between the two.

However this might result in you changing a lot of code possibly

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm purely using **Webcam.js** not **Threex.ArToolkitSource.js**. And your soution not working for me